# How to change the workspace location from a jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins, how do I design a plugin to take user's input on where to create the workspace on the filesystem?

I came across [WorkspaceLocator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extension+points#Extensionpoints-jenkins.slaves.WorkspaceLocator) but not sure how to use it. An example would be great.

[edit]

I want to be able to do this from the plugin's code. As in, for a particular type of project, the workspace should be created in some hard coded location that is declared in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the workspace at `Advance Project options` -> `Use custom workspace` under your job configuration.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Maybe I wasn't clear in the question, I've edited it.

Comment: I think, you have to override the `env.WORKSPACE` in your code to use custom workspace. I am not sure why do you want to get the workspace folder as input when the Job config already provides that.

Comment: Where exactly is the Advance Project options? I can not find it anywhere.